# Not getting email using PHP

Tags: php, email

I want to send a conformation email using php code. I have tried all solutions such as `mail()` and phpmailer but nothing is working. Here is my code for `mail()`

```
ini_set(sendmail_from, "xyz@domainname.net" );
ini_set(SMTP, "aspmx2.googlemail.com" );
ini_set(smtp_port, 25 );
$username = "xyz";
 $password = "password";
$to=$email;
$subject="Activate you account"; 
$message="
Hello $fullname, \n \n
    ";
$headers="From: xyz@ domainname.net";
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
die ("You have been registerd. Check you email to activate your account!");
```

I am getting `“You have been registered. Check you email to activate your account”` message on the page, but I am not getting an email.

I tried without `ini_set()` but it is still not working. I also have set SMTP and port in php.ini file but it is still not working.

Please help!!
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the club. Sending email with PHP is very dificult. I have not succeeded yet.

Comment: [Gmail's SMTP server](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287) is secured by SSL/TLS and requires authentication, something PHP's `mail()` can not do.

Comment: Many free hostings on the web don't let you send emails using other SMTP servers. And if you are on your own PC, make sure PHP can access the web. Check Apache settings, etc.

Comment: This could be applicable:
http://www.000webhost.com/forum/web-programming/11199-php-mail-not-delivering-gmail-google-apps.html

Answer (score 4):

You're not actually setting the username/password for the `mail()` call. All you're doing is setting some variables, and then not using those variables in any way for the mail. So your attempt to send mail through Google fails, because you're not authenticating.

But as other answers have said, don't use the built-in `mail()` function. Use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) instead. They're far easier to use, handle all the ugly stuff of doing file attachments and multi-part MIME mail, and do it all behind a nice OOP interface.

Answer (score 1):

To points here:

You're calling `mail` without checking the return code -- which means that you know that you're *attempting* to send a message, but you have no idea whether it succeeds. Which isn't helpful for debugging.

And second, Gmail requires an encrypted connection before they will allow you to authenticate.  And a standard SMTP connection isn't encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending e-mails using [PHPmailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) 
i have heard lots of great things about it.

sample of PHPMailer config

```
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";  
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";  
$mail->Port = 465;  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication  
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com"; // SMTP username  
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password
```

Comment: I used phpmailer to send email. If I use $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; and $port = 465; then I successfully getting email. But IF i use same script for $host ="aspmx2.googlemail.com"; and $port = "25"; then getting error that "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. " Any suggestions ?? Please help

Comment: The first way is the proper way to send the e-mail , thats how you should do it !